# Boost not building all libraries

Tags: boost

In the project-config.jam, I see a line

```
$
# List of --with-<library> and --without-<library>$
# options. If left empty, all libraries will be built.$
# Options specified on the command line completely$
# override this variable.$
libraries =  ;$
```

and still

```
bootstrap.sh --prefix=/my/target/location/
./b2 install
```

does not build all the libraries. Only the one below:

```
Component configuration:

- atomic                   : building
- chrono                   : building
- container                : building
- context                  : building
- coroutine                : building
- coroutine2               : building
- date_time                : building
- exception                : building
- fiber                    : building
- filesystem               : building
- graph                    : building
- graph_parallel           : building
- iostreams                : building
- locale                   : building
- log                      : building
- math                     : building
- metaparse                : building
- mpi                      : building
- program_options          : building
- python                   : building
- random                   : building
- regex                    : building
- serialization            : building
- signals                  : building
- system                   : building
- test                     : building
- thread                   : building
- timer                    : building
- type_erasure             : building
- wave                     : building
```

I faced the problem, becaues circular_buffer isnt available in the component.

Comment: Are those dollar signs present in the actual file? They should not be, and there should be a bunch of other `option.set` lines after that.

Answer (score 0):

Not all Boost components need to be built into libraries - many are 'header only', so the entire implementation is defined in the `.hpp` files.

It looks like the list of components above are just those which need a corresponding library, which is what the 'build' step is doing.

Run the install script and verify that you have `include/boost/circular_buffer.hpp` present in the target, as this is indeed a header-only component.

Comment: include/boost/circular_buffer.hpp is in the source ( boost ) but not my target that I defined using a --prefix. Maybe ./b2 does not copy all the includes to the target? How can I force the install script to do it?

Comment: After showing the "Component Build:" lines, you should see a huge number of lines showing "common.copy <filename>" and one of those should be `.../include/boost/circular_buffer.hpp`. I just downloaded the tarsal, ran the same two commands you list above, and verified that circular buffer header is indeed installed into the target folder. There should be no need to force anything. What gets printed after the above?

Comment: I am sure, files are being skipped. I saw boost/filesystem.hpp is also not copied. Please see the pastebin.

Comment: The pastebin doesn't show the entire session's output. Use the `script` command to capture everything to a file, and start from scratch. Delete the target folder and clean any build products. Then start the capture session, run the bootstrap command then the b2 install command.